# REST call with POST doesn't show response message

Tags: html, angularjs, rest

I'm trying to make a POST call with AngularJS and see if everything worked by getting the response message, response status, etc.

What I want is to see if my POST went okay and had no problem with the service call.

Edit: syntax error corrected

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.hello = {id: "1", name: "ERA"};
    $scope.newId= "";
    $scope.newName = "";
    $scope.sendPost = function() {
        var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
             id: $scope.newId,
              name: $scope.newName
            })
        });
        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/academi-co/resources/tags/languages/", data).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.hello = data;
            
            if (response.data)

             $scope.msg = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";

             }, function (response) {

             $scope.msg = "Service not Exists";

             $scope.statusval = response.status;

             $scope.statustext = response.statusText;

             $scope.headers = response.headers();
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='myApp'>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form ng-submit="sendPost()">
        <input ng-model="newId"/>
        <input ng-model="newName"/>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

<p>{{hello.id}}</p>

<p>{{hello.name}}</p>

<p>Output Message : {{msg}}</p>

<p>StatusCode: {{statusval}}</p>

<p>Status: {{statustext}}</p>

<p>Response Headers: {{headers}}</p>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: First correct the syntax errors please.

Comment: replace `.success` with `.then`

Comment: Changed it, doesn't seem to help. What is the difference between .success and .then ?

Comment: `success` is deprecated...see $http docs

Answer (score -1):

I changed the code a some code, maybe try this.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.hello = {id: "1", name: "ERA"};
    $scope.newId= "";
    $scope.newName = "";
    $scope.sendPost = function() {
        var data = {
            json: JSON.stringify({
                id: $scope.newId,
                name: $scope.newName
            })
        };

        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/academi-co/resources/tags/languages/", data).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.hello = data;

            if (response.data)

                $scope.msg = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";

        }, function (response) {

            $scope.msg = "Service not Exists";

            $scope.statusval = response.status;

            $scope.statustext = response.statusText;

            $scope.headers = response.headers();
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: The problem persist, it only refreshes the page but no output of the message either error or not.. :/

Comment: That is not what you asked, the initial problem was the syntax error. To fix this, you have to remove the form tags and run the code after a click of the button not when the form is submitted/